# Making radio buttons in netsuite

Tags: html, netsuite

I'm currently trying to make radio buttons in netsuite, I'm have a hard time finding a good resource for help. Has anyone went through this process before?

Comment: When you ask a Netsuite question you'll likely get better answers if you specify the context of your question. For instance this question likely refers to a form on a Suitelet but the question should make the context specific.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *officially* add a custom Radio field to a NetSuite form using the UI customisations, they are only available in SuiteScript.

Looking to add Radio Buttons using the NetSuite form customisations anyway? [Check out my new question/answer here!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78105956/4561907)

Radio fields are only supported when working with a `nlobjForm` object in SuiteScript 1 or SuiteScript 2.

**Official code sample (SuiteScript 1):**

```
function radioButtonSamples(request, response)
{
var form = nlapiCreateForm('Sample Form');

// create a field of type 'label' - this field type holds no data and is used for display purposes only
form.addField('orgtypelabel','label','What type of organization are you?').setLayoutType('startrow');

/* add fields of type 'radio'. Notice that this set of radio buttons all specify 'orgtype' as the field
* name for each button. Each radio button is distinguished by the value specified in
* the 'source' parameter. By default, this set of radio fields will appear vertically since
* no layout type has been specified
*/
form.addField('orgtype', 'radio', 'Business To Consumer', 'b2c');
form.addField('orgtype', 'radio','Business To Business','b2b');
form.addField('orgtype', 'radio','Non-Profit','nonprofit');

//default the "Business to Business" radio button as selected when the page loads
form.getField('orgtype', 'b2b' ).setDefaultValue( 'b2b' );

/* now add the second set of radio buttons. Notice that this group also shares the same
* value for name, which is 'companysize'. Also note the use of the setLayoutType method.
* Use this when you want to position the buttons horizontally.
*/
form.addField('companysizelabel','label','How big is your organization?').setLayoutType('startrow');
form.addField('companysize', 'radio','Small (0-99 employees)', 's').setLayoutType('midrow');
form.addField('companysize', 'radio','Medium (100-999 employees)','m').setLayoutType('midrow');
form.addField('companysize', 'radio','Large (1000+ employees)','l').setLayoutType('endrow');

response.writePage( form );
}
```

**Above Code Refactored into SuiteScript 2.0:**

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget'], function (serverWidget) {
    function onRequest(context) {

        var form = serverWidget.createForm({
            title: 'Sample Form'
        });

        // create a field of type 'label' - this field type holds no data and is used for display purposes only
        form.addField({
            id: 'orgtypelabel',
            label: 'What type of organization are you?',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.LABEL
        }).updateLayoutType({
            layoutType: serverWidget.FieldLayoutType.STARTROW
        });

        /* add fields of type 'radio'. Notice that this set of radio buttons all specify 'orgtype' as the field
        * name for each button. Each radio button is distinguished by the value specified in
        * the 'source' parameter. By default, this set of radio fields will appear vertically since
        * no layout type has been specified
        */
        form.addField({
            id: 'orgtype',
            label: 'Business To Consumer',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
            source: 'b2c'
        });
        form.addField({
            id: 'orgtype',
            label: 'Business To Business',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
            source: 'b2b'
        });
        form.addField({
            id: 'orgtype',
            label: 'Non-Profit',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
            source: 'nonprofit'
        });

        //default the "Business to Business" radio button as selected when the page loads
        form.updateDefaultValues({
            values: { orgtype: 'b2b' }
        })

        /* now add the second set of radio buttons. Notice that this group also shares the same
        * value for name, which is 'companysize'. Also note the use of the setLayoutType method.
        * Use this when you want to position the buttons horizontally.
        */
        form.addField({
            id: 'companysizelabel',
            label: 'How big is your organization?',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.LABEL
        }).updateLayoutType({
            layoutType: serverWidget.FieldLayoutType.STARTROW
        });
        form.addField({
            id: 'companysize',
            label: 'Small (0-99 employees)',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
            source: 's'
        }).updateLayoutType({
            layoutType: serverWidget.FieldLayoutType.MIDROW
        });
        form.addField({
            id: 'companysize',
            label: 'Medium (100-999 employees)',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
            source: 'm'
        }).updateLayoutType({
            layoutType: serverWidget.FieldLayoutType.MIDROW
        });
        form.addField({
            id: 'companysize',
            label: 'Large (1000+ employees)',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.RADIO,
            source: 'l'
        }).updateLayoutType({
            layoutType: serverWidget.FieldLayoutType.ENDROW
        });

        context.response.writePage(form);
    }
    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };
});
```

**Result:**
[image: Example of form containing radio buttons]

Official Reference (SuiteScript 1): https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n3144618.html#bridgehead_N3149879

Comment: I will be posting a separate question and answer soon with a workaround that will allow you to add Radio buttons via the NetSuite form customisation UI! I will add a link here when it is up.

Comment: Just wondering if you ever got this done?

Comment: If you want to add RADIO BUTTONS using the Form Customisation feature, check out my new answer! https://stackoverflow.com/q/78105956/4561907