# How can I create a Radio button Custom Field and add it to a NetSuite form?

Tags: user-interface, netsuite

I would like to add a Radio button to a NetSuite form using the "Customise Form" feature however it doesn't appear possible to create a Radio Custom Field.

I tried creating a new Custom Field in NetSuite, in the Type field there are various entries such as Check Box, List/Record, Multiple Select, but there is no choice to create a Radio field.

Answer (score 1):

NetSuite does not officially support a "Radio" type field, therefore we need to do a little workaround to make it happen!

### If you're using the standard NetSuite form customiser

I have created a little script you can use to easily add Radio buttons to any form – you only need to do this ONCE and you can use it on as many different forms for as many different radio buttons as you like!

Create a **Custom Field** of type **Inline HTML** and add it on every form that you want **Radio Buttons** to appear. Under the **Validation & Defaulting** tab add the following into the **Default Value** field. (don't worry, it's invisible to the user)

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    try {
        var t = '<div class="uir-field-wrapper uir-inline-tag uir-onoff"><span class="uir-field" data-nsps-type="field_input"><span style="white-space: nowrap; padding:0px;"><input {{CHECKED}} onchange="nlapiSetFieldValue(this.dataset.name,this.value);" data-name="{{OPTION_NAME}}" name="radio_{{OPTION_NAME}}" type="radio" value="{{OPTION_VALUE}}" class="radio" id="radio_{{RADIO_ID}}"></span></span><span class="smallgraytextnolink uir-label"><span class="labelSpanEdit smallgraytextnolink"><label for="radio_{{RADIO_ID}}"><a class="smallgraytextnolink">{{OPTION_TEXT}}</a></label></span></span></div>';
        var field_labels = document.getElementsByClassName('uir-label');
        var radio_fields = [];
        for (var i=0,totali=field_labels.length; i<totali; i++) { 
            if(field_labels[i].querySelector('a').text.slice(-3).toLowerCase() != '[r]') continue;
            field_labels[i].querySelector('a').text = field_labels[i].querySelector('a').text = field_labels[i].querySelector('a').text.slice(0,-3);
            var id = field_labels[i].id.slice(0,-17);
            var orig_field = document.getElementById(id+'_fs');
            orig_field.style.display = 'none';
            var orig_field_parent = orig_field.parentElement;
            var options_element = orig_field.querySelector('[data-options]');
            var default_opt_index = options_element.dataset.defaultOption;
            var options = JSON.parse(options_element.dataset.options);
            var radio_html = '';
            for(var x=0,totalx=options.length; x<totalx; x++) {
                if(!(options[x].value > 0)) continue;
                var h1 = t;
                h1 = h1.replace(/{{RADIO_ID}}/g,i+'_'+x);
                h1 = h1.replace(/{{OPTION_NAME}}/g,id);
                h1 = h1.replace('{{OPTION_VALUE}}',options[x].value);
                h1 = h1.replace('{{OPTION_TEXT}}',options[x].text);
                h1 = h1.replace('{{CHECKED}}',(x == default_opt_index ? 'checked' : ''));
                radio_html += h1;
            }
            var radio_holder_element = document.createElement('div');
            radio_holder_element.innerHTML = radio_html;
            orig_field_parent.appendChild(radio_holder_element);
        } 
    } catch(e) {
        console.error('Error converting Drop-down selections to Radio Buttons.',e);
    }
});
</script>
```

It should look like this:
[image: Adding script to Custom Field]

Once you have created this Custom Field, ensure it is Enabled/Shown on any Form(s) that you want to use Radio Buttons.

Now comes the fun part! You can turn any **List/Record** type field into a **Radio Button** simply by adding **[R]** to the end of the **Label**!

****BEFORE** Radio Button Fix script:**
[image: BEFORE Radio Button Fix script]

****AFTER** Radio Button Fix script:**
[image: AFTER Radio Button Fix script]

That's all there is to it. You can change the label on as many different **List/Record** type fields as you like to add **[R]** at the end and they will then appear as **Radio buttons**.

*DISCLAIMER: NetSuite does not support DOM manipulation, which is how this workaround functions. Future updates to the NetSuite user interface could break this functionality. If this occurs, simply delete the Inline HTML Custom Field to return the original List/Record drop-down selectors.*

---

### If you are NOT using the NetSuite Form Customiser

If you are instead using SuiteScript 1 or 2, you can follow the instructions I posted on another question: [Create Radio Buttons using SuiteScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762496/4561907)

Comment: Creative workaround - upvoted!  However, I think it would be appropriate to include a disclaimer that NetSuite doesn't support DOM manipulation, and that this could break with a NetSuite update.

Comment: Will add a note into the answer. Also, I wrapped the whole thing in a try/catch block so even if NetSuite do change the DOM it shouldn't break the page.